# python-binance order_limit_buy() APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I am having issues with executing a limit buy order with python-binance. The sell limit order function executes just fine. I had a balance 35.95302628 USDT in my account.  `0.06545172930180404 * 548.26772 USDT = 35.89 USDT`.

```
self.client = Client(KEY, Secret)

def round_decimals_down(self, number:float, decimals:int=2):
    """
    Returns a value rounded down to a specific number of decimal places.
    """
    self.number = number
    self.decimals = decimals
    if not isinstance(self.decimals, int):
        raise TypeError("decimal places must be an integer")
    elif self.decimals < 0:
        raise ValueError("decimal places has to be 0 or more")
    elif self.decimals == 0:
        return math.floor(self.number)

    factor = 10 ** self.decimals
    return math.floor(self.number * factor) / factor


def sell(self, symbol, offerSellPrice):
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.sellSymbol = (self.symbol + str("USDT"))
    self.quantity = self.cursor.execute("SELECT " + self.symbol + "Quantity FROM Table WHERE tID = (SELECT MAX(tID) FROM Table)").fetchval()
    self.offerSellPrice = offerSellPrice

    self.order = self.client.order_limit_sell(symbol=self.sellSymbol,
                                                      quantity=self.round_decimals_down(self.quantity, 6),
                                                      price=self.round_decimals_down(self.offerSellPrice, 2))


def buy(self, symbol, cryptoQuantity, offerBuyPrice):
    self.buySymbol = (symbol + str("USDT"))
    self.cryptoQuantity = cryptoQuantity
    self.offerBuyPrice = offerBuyPrice
    
    self.order = self.client.order_limit_buy(symbol=self.buySymbol,
                                      quantity=self.round_decimals_down(self.cryptoQuantity, 6),
                                       price=self.round_decimals_down(self.offerBuyPrice, 2))

buy('BCH', 0.06545172930180404, 548.26772)
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\CryptoBot\A9.py", line 891, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\CryptoBot\A9.py", line 881, in main
    s.operations()
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\CryptoBot\A9.py", line 604, in operations
    self.buy(self.cryptoToBuy, self.rawCryptoQuantityBCH, self.offerBuyPriceBCH) 
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\CryptoBot\A9.py", line 422, in buy
    self.order = self.client.order_limit_buy(symbol=self.buySymbol,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1460, in order_limit_buy
    return self.order_limit(timeInForce=timeInForce, **params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1424, in order_limit
    return self.create_order(**params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 1387, in create_order
    return self._post('order', True, data=params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 374, in _post
    return self._request_api('post', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 334, in _request_api
    return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 315, in _request
    return self._handle_response(self.response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 324, in _handle_response
    raise BinanceAPIException(response, response.status_code, response.text)
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE
```

```
info = client.get_symbol_info('BCHUSDT')
print(info)
```

returns:

```
{'symbol': 'BCHUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'BCH', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': True, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.01000000', 'maxPrice': '100000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.01000000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '3410.06217369', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT', 'MARGIN']}
```

`LOT_SIZE`:

```
{'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00001000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.00001000'}
```

My order quantity is larger than the `'minQt': '0.00001000'`

I have also tried this at a precision (quantity) of 8 and received the same error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

LOT_SIZE is the number of decimal places you are using.
Your order must comply with the 'stepSize' in your case: 0.00001000

```
0.06545172930180404
      ^
0.00001
```

0.06545 -> your value has to be like this

I made an algorithm and made it available on github with a function that rounds the value according to the 'stepSize'
https://github.com/gustavoara/binance-lot_size